# Meaning of 1[pointer] in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, array-pointer

Reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) I found this example:

```cpp
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* p = &a[2];
std::cout << p[1] << p[-1] << 1[p] << (-1)[p] << '\n'; // 4242
```

I am confused about the meaning of `1[p]` and `(-1)[p]`. Asking for help elsewhere I was told: "`1[ptr]` is equivalent to `*(1 * sizeof(T) + ptr)`". So I understand mechanically why it outputs `4242`, but I find it hard to reason about. As it's nonsensical to put a pointer in square brackets usually, and is an error by itself:

```cpp
[cling]$ 1[p]
(int) 4
[cling]$ [p]
input_line_15:2:3: error: 'p' cannot be captured because it does not have
      automatic storage duration
 [p]
  ^
```

Is this just a special case of the syntax I should just memorize, or am I misunderstanding some logic behind the statement?

Comment: There's really nothing to it aside from them choosing to make the operation commutative in that way. You don't really need to know it. It's more a fun trivia fact than something that you'll ever want to write yourself or have good reason to expect to read from anyone else's code.

Comment: `[p]` is the equivalent of `p[]` which is also invalid.  Does that clear up the confusion?  Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Comment: Did you read point 1 of the section to which you linked? That plus the first sentence after the list explains it as well as I could. (So no need for me to waste my time if that explanation is not enough.)

Comment: `1[pointer]` means the same as `pointer[1]`. Blame Dennis Ritchie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume `p` is a pointer or array, and `n` is an integer. When the compiler sees this:

```
p[n]
```

It logically interprets that expression as:

```
*(p+n)
```

So when it sees this:

```
n[p]
```

The compiler treats it as:

```
*(n+p)
```

Which is algebraically the same as `*(p+n)`

Hence: `p[n] == n[p]`